# Filtering Beer with Coffee Filter

Tags: brewing, filtering

I want to know if anybody has tried filtering beer with coffee filters?
I'm tempted to play with this idea at a later date. I would be concerned about aerating the beer too much, so again has anyone made any enclosed rigs for the coffee filters?

Because the microns of the filter is not heavily regulated, I'm imagining some sort of spaced-out-multi-layered structure of filters clamped together could work.

Anyone have any examples, tutorials or projects with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you do it post fermentation, you will oxidize the beer badly.  Not a good idea.

Comment: There are ways of filtering beer that don't introduce oxygen. A google search should give you what you need.

Comment: Tobias, if you know of a method (or find one with a search) please describe and link to it here so that others may find it easily also.

Comment: You push it from keg to another using CO2 with a filter in between.  That eliminates the chance of oxidation.

Comment: co2 is good, but I was thinking of gravity fed way. Filter rig is below the FV and above the BV but beer enters the rig through the bottom filling upwards pushing air out the top and then into the exit tube at the top of the rig towards the botterling bucket/keg/bottles. I believe this would be minimise the air to beer contact.

Comment: That won't work.  You need more pressure to push the beer through the filter.